# Why can't this index signature be optional?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TypeScript, there's a pre-defined type called `Partial<T>`. It is defines like this:

```
type Partial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}
```

Apparently, the index signature is marked as optional, and this works. If I try to do the same thing like this:

```
interface IDictionary<T> {
  [ key: string ]?: T
}
```

TypeScript complains about the `?`. Is this because interfaces may not contain optional fields, or what is the reason for this?

Comment: `Partial` definition is a mapped type and it says: "Go over all members and add optional modifier". What are you trying to achieve by marking index signature as optional?

Comment: [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) look similar but are not the same.  Index signatures cannot be marked optional, and in fact are always treated as optional (in the sense that you are not required to have all possible index keys in a matching object); there's no way to say "required".  I agree that the syntax is confusing and possibly misleading, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, typescript interfaces allow optional fields. The reason is it makes no sense, *logically*.

`Partial<T>` is adding a constraint on how the key should look like => `P in keyof T`.
If you would remove the `?` here this would mean `Partial<T>` is the same as `T`.

```js
interface Car {
  brand: string;
  color: string;
}

// this is exactly the same as the interface declaration below
type PartialCar = Partial<Car>;

// this is exactly the same as the type above
interface PartialCar = { 
  brand?: string;
  color?: string;
}

const carWithoutColor: PartialCar = { brand: "BMW" }
const thisIsStillAPartialCar: PartialCar = {}
```

For your `IDictionary<T>` it's different. You are not adding a constraint on the key (just saying it's **any** `string`). So *it makes no sense* to say it can be optional because it's anyway optional (in terms of it could be **any** `string`).
In your `IDictionary<T>` you are just adding a constraint on the value part which needs to be type of `T`.

```js
const numberDictionary: IDictionary<number> = { someStupidKey: 1, oneMoreKey: 2 }
const stringDictionary: IDictionary<string> = { someStupidKeyAWFSAFWAFW: "foo", oneMoreKey: "bar" }

// typescript will assume that "someVariable" is a number
const someVariable = numberDictionary.thisIsUndefined;

// which is why this will not end up in a compile error but a runtime error
const someResult =  1 + someVariable;
```

As you can see every key is already *optional* with your declartion of `IDictionary<T>`

Comment: This sounds correct, still it leaves the question open as to why `[P in keyof T]` means *all* keys of T, while `[P in string]` just means *some* (*any*) string. The fact that no finite number of keys would satisfy the constraint "all strings" does not justify the ambiguous notation imo.

Comment: I'd argue that it is *redundant* (and unsupported) to say that index signature keys are optional, not that it "makes no sense".  It certainly makes sense, and some redundant constructs are permitted in TS (e.g., `{a?: string}` and `{a?: string | undefined}` are both permitted and mean the same thing; `{[K in keyof T]?: T[K]}` and `{[K in keyof T]+?: T[K]}` are both permitted and mean the same thing)