# How to specify type for multiple properties inside of an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

I have this prop that I'll be passing down:

`checkboxesState`

its original value is an empty object

> {}

but it will change when user clicks on checkboxes, so it can look like this:

```
{
 "option1": true,
 "option2": true,
 "option3": true,
 "option4": true,
 ...
 ...
}
```

My question is, How can I define its type in the interface?

I have this but I have a feeling it's missing something:

```
interface FieldProps {
   checkboxState: { [key: string]: boolean };
}
```

Comment: You might want `{ [key: string]?: true }`. Or `Partial<Record<string, true>>`. Or maybe you allow `false` values as well, so using `boolean` instead of `true`?

Comment: when I do: { [key: string]?: boolean };  typescript throws an error saying: ';' expected

Comment: Oh [I was confusing index signatures and mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57337815/1048572), apparently the former cannot be optional.

Comment: I use the adapter pattern through out my applications. I found that using a class instead of an interface has more advantages and can solve the default values you are looking for.

Comment: @Natdrip A `class` won't help here when there are arbitrary options. A `Set<string>` might be an option for arbitrarily-named boolean flags though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try

```
Record<string,boolean>
```

This means that all keys must be a string and all values must be a boolean

Comment: but in the beginning the object is completely empty. Would this still work?

Comment: Yeah it would, I just checked.

Comment: `Record` results in `{ [key: string]: boolean };` so this answer doesn't bring anything new

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know that. Records look a bit cleaner wouldn't you say.

Comment: it depends. The version that it results in is more flexible

Comment: @wonderflame so for my question would you say this could be a good approach:  checkboxStates: EmptyObject | { [key: string]: boolean };   EmptyObject being defined as: type EmptyObject = Record<string, never>;

Comment: I think the second is cleaner and looks more readable, but it's up to you, also isn't it supposed to be Record<string, boolean>.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is what you want

type Option = Record<string, boolean>

```
const obj: Option = {
  option1: true,
  option2: true,
  option3: true,
  abctest: true,
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a number. The option1 was just an example. It could actually be "abctest"